# Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError I allow all domains in console

Tags: google-maps

Please Help to repair this problem
Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error.....There is a screen
http://prntscr.com/j0f3xa
I allow all domains in console

Comment: What is the URL(s) that you have authorized in the [API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) for the API key you are using to load the Javascript API?

Comment: I use Google Places API Web Service

Comment: That is my url http://prntscr.com/j0f6y1

Comment: If you are allowing all domains with that wildcard, why not just remove the HTTP referrers completely and only use API restrictions on the API key?

Comment: Even when I use without limitation I receive the same error

Comment: The first screenshot shows that you are loading the [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#standard-auth), not the [Places API web service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key#if_you_are_using_the_standard_api_name_webservice_places). Without more information, we can't be sure if you are using the correct API key along with the correct Javascript API URL load in your website.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/j0h15n  It is mean turn off So this API is turned on http://prntscr.com/j0h27o

Comment: Also I include not local domain and it is not working too for me http://prntscr.com/j0h39u

Comment: As I said earlier, you are *not* loading the Places API web service, you are loading the Javascript API. Also, from the last screenshot, you are loading the Javascript API with an API key that is only authorized for use with the Places API web service. You should add the Javascript API as an authorized API for your API key. Please review the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#api-key-error) for using API keys with different Maps APIs.

Comment: @Preston THANK YOU! I am so lucky I found your buried comment on this unpopular duplicated question with no answer. Seriously. I have spent hours looking for this. You saved me. Emphasizing my gratitude to help the next poor soul in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's also in the comment from @Preston -- as of now (Nov. '18), the error message from the Google API - that there is a problem with a missing referrer allowance, might be misleading.

If the JS API is enabled for the project, but still not for the concrete API KEY, this error is displayed.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eav6v.png)